# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-x}^{0}\sin(t^3)\,dt$

Tags: calculus, elementary-functions

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-x}^{0}\sin(t^3)\,dt.$$

I use L'Hopital's Rule and get -1/4. The solution says 1/4. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int \sin(t^3)dt}{ x^4}$ or $\lim_{x \to 0}\int\frac{ sin(t^3)dt}{ t^4}$?

Comment: the definite integral on the numerator is from -x to 0.

Comment: Is $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\int_{-x}^0 \sin(t^3)dt}{ x^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Since in a neighbourhood of zero:
$$\sin(t^3) = t^3+o(t^4)$$
we have:
$$\int_{-x}^{0}\sin(t^3)\,dt = \int_{-x}^{0}t^3 dt + o\left(\int_{-x}^{0}t^4\,dt\right)$$
hence:
$$\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{-x}^{0}\sin(t^3)\,dt=-\frac{1}{4}+o(x)$$
as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\int \limits _{0}^{-x} \sin(t^3)dt}{ x^4} \stackrel{LH}{=} \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{ \sin((-x)^3)(-x)'}{ 4x^3} =  \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{ \sin(-x^3)(-1)}{ 4x^3}  = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{ \sin(x^3)}{ 4x^3}  =  \dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: This is impossible. The integral is negative while $x^4$ is positive in a right neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: Ahh yes, I'll fix it :)

Comment: Thanks Jack, I also got -1/4

Comment: if we reverse the bounds of top integral, we will get +1/4... but that would be like changing the question to fit the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Without bothering to compute the limit, it's easy to see that the limit (if it exists) cannot be positive:  For all sufficiently small positive values of $x$, we are integrating (from left to right) over the interval $[-x,0]$, where the function $\sin(t^3)$ is *negative*.